# nginx no speed limitation for a connection

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, performance, cdn, slow-connection

I have a server with **nginx** installed on it to serve some files for downloading. I also didn't change *default configuration* of **nginx**.

Problem is that when I try to download from this server it seems there is a limitation for a connection because when I try to download with **axel** with 10 connection it's about *3X* faster than **wget** with one connection.

How can I remove this limitation so that users can download with maximum speed from this server with one connection?

is Using **axel** faster because of my configuration or it's because of characteristic of network and internet?

**UPDATE:**

After first comment that indicates my comparison was wrong, I changed my test to `axel -n 1` Vs. `axel -n 10`. Now there is no much difference between them but using more than one connection is still a little bit faster. (*780KB/s* for one connection and *830KB/s* for ten connection).

Is this difference irrelevant to **nginx** configuration?

Comment: So you compare axel and wget and then come to the conclusion that there must be a problem in nginx? Wouldn't it be better to compare `axel -n 1` and `axel -n 10` for a start?

Comment: @Oliver you're right. My conclusion was incorrect. Now by comparing `axel -n 1` and `axel -n 10` difference isn't **3x**. for one connection speed is 780 KB/s and for 10 connection speed is about 830 KB/s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This difference is probably not due to nginx, but more likely to your TCP stack (either on the client or on the server).

The most obvious difference is that by using 10 simultaneous connections, you will use up to 10 times as much memory for TCP buffers than with a single connection. This also means that by increasing the buffer size you have a good chance of improving the throughput of a single connection (at the same time you will probably reduce the number of connections your server can handle - there's always two sides to every story).

There are dozens of parameters for tuning the TCP stack. See the `tcp(7)` man page for more information.

If you just want to play with the buffer sizes you can do this through some files in `/proc`:

- `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max`
- `/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max`
- `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem`
- `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem`

Don't forget this applies to the server as well as the client.